# Clicking objects created with Handlebars doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, handlebars.js

I upload all the stuff so you could see what I mean: http://nonemoticoner.com/learning/jquery/clickbug/

The point is that I cannot click divs I created with Handlebar, this is:
**firstthumbin** (id),
**restthumbing** (class)
They exist on thumbnails so I could use them to switch between galleries.

In **script.js** I created handlers in jQuery so I could click ones. None of them work :(

```
$('div#firstthumbing').on('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked first');
    changeSli(galInView, 0);
});

$('div.restthumbing').on('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked rest');
    changeSli(galInView, 1);
});

$('.thumb').on('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked first thumb');
    changeSli(galInView, 0);
});
```

I don't know why but a little above click works correctly. Is that because of Handlebars? How can I solve it? Please help me, I really tried to fix it by myself but this thing is really new to me. Click always used to work for me.

Comment: You should probably bind the click event to the parent/ancestor container: `$(container).on('click', 'div#firstthumbing' , function(){`

Comment: You don't have Handlebars defined in that page. You could either load it from http://cdnjs.com or locally.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. Tried for #content, body, html, document. Still fails to log 'clicked' :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the firstthumbing after "onload" event, and you click function not binding becouse the element doesn't exist on DOM whe you run the script to haddle the click function.

Try to call the click function before create you clickable thumbs.